# What is high-energy optical conductivity?

Tags: experimental-physics

Can anyone explain to me that what the technique of high energy optical conductivity is?

I’m Year 1 Physics major.

Comment: This is not well known (to me at least). Is it as in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1101.3059)? You could add more context to your Question.

Comment: @KeithMcClary as much I wish to, this is about a topic that our lecturer wishes us to talk about and the term "high-energy optical conductivity" is the only phrase that was given, without any added information.